# Objective-C dynamic object creation memory issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I've been putting on with a strange issue in my iPhone program for a while.

To make long story short: I have an XML which contains data about tree-like composition. I've wrote a parser which constructs a tree from the XML.

Somewhere in DataSource class I have following method:

```
 - (id)loadAllData {
   if (self.doc != nil) {
    GDataXMLElement *root = [self.doc rootElement];
    Component *component = [Component componentWithRoot:root];
    NSLog(@"%@", component);
    return component;
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Factory method looks like this:

```
+ (id)componentWithRoot:(GDataXMLNode*)element {
  id<iComponent> component = nil;
  NSString *clsName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Element", [element name]];

  // Will return instance of a class or |nil| if class is not loaded.
  Class cls = NSClassFromString(clsName);

  if (cls != nil) {
    component = [[cls alloc] init];

    // dies on next line
    NSLog(@"created %@", component);

    // Seems that we have corresponding model class
    if (component != nil) {

      //... setting attrubutes for this model

      //... trying to find child elements and add them to the component instance.
    }
  }
  return component;
}
```

Also when I stop GDB on line where I call `alloc` and `init` methods and try to call them in debugger I see next error log:

```
(gdb) po component

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x828282df
0x01052a67 in objc_msgSend ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (_NSPrintForDebugger) will be abandoned.
```

So the situation is: somehow my program starts up and displays values that I need correctly. But when I try to do something with my `component`, program just crashes. Any ideas? How can I find a error? I don't any reasons why `NSLog(@"created %@", component);` crashes application and so do other actions with `component` (actually I want to encode it to an archive).

Thanks in advance!

---

*Update*

This is piece of factory method code with comments

```
+ (id)componentWithRoot:(GDataXMLNode*)element {
  id<iComponent> component = nil;
  NSString *clsName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Element", [element name]];
  NSLog(@"%@", clsName);
  // Will return instance of a class or |nil| if class is not loaded.
  Class cls = NSClassFromString(clsName);
  if (cls != nil) {
    component = [[[cls alloc] init] autorelease];
    // Seems that we have corresponding model class
    if (component != nil) {

      [component setTitle:[element name]]; 
      /*
       when I run app I have first element named ConfigElement. 
       Code runes fine to this point and even properties are set correct.
       But if I set breakpoint at this line and type in consle 
         po component
       I get message which is posted below
      */
```

(gdb) po component

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x828282df
0x01052a67 in objc_msgSend ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (_NSPrintForDebugger) will be abandoned.

Since this happens I want to make sure that all init methods are correct.
Here what I am doing:

first -  check that name of class is `ConfigElement` - yes

second - look at `ConfigElement` `init` - everything ok:

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}
```

third - look at super (`Composite`) initializer:

```
- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    children_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}
```

then look for super initializer again (`Component` initializer now) - seems good again:

```
- (id)init {
  if ((self=[super init])) {
    title_ = nil;
    name_ = nil;
    icon_ = nil;
    parent_ = nil;
    children_ = nil;
  }
  return self;  
}
```

Since `Component` is a subclass of NSObject I don't need to bother about super initializer again and could probably remove `if` statement but let it be. Also all these initilizers are designated and they are actually called at the moment of `init`.

So why I am getting that error msg in GDB?

Comment: What happens if you do `NSLog(@"component %@", cls)` after the `cls != nil` line? Also, why are you using this rather than the built in serialization/archiving tools?

Comment: You're leaking memory here. Unless your factory method is called something like "new", "copy", or "create" then it should return an autoreleased object. As to why it's crashing, I'm not sure.

Comment: @toiletseat I need to use this because I can't store objects in simple plist due to compatibility needs. Answering your question - program just dies. I don't see any reasons because I've imported corresponding classes before, `clsName` was set correctly, `cls` also is not `null`. And when I do `cls alloc` nothing but correct pointer should be returned, am I right?

Comment: @Brian Donovan yep memory leak is here but this is not a problem - at the moment I don't care if memory leaks so I removed `autorelease` because I thought it was the reason of error :)

Comment: @Dig, have you overridden the `init` method in the classes that `Component` instantiates? Are you definately returning `self` from the init method? Does it work if you hard-code in the name of a class you are trying to instantiate? I'd be interested in seeing the `init` method of a class you are trying to instantiate that fails.

Comment: @toiletseat Yes it works when I hard code class names - I tried to create empty project and added new simple classes. Posted my code here: https://gist.github.com/904194 It may look complex but the idea is to implement composition pattern - class hierarchy looks like: App(Confing, etc)Element : Composite : Component.

Comment: @Dig, the exception you are getting (in objc_msgSend) generally means you are sendnig a message to an object that has been freed, or isn't actually a valid object (ie an int, or a random area of memory). The error is happening when you call the `description` method on your object, either via `NSLog` or the GDB `po`, I don't suppose you've override `description` in your `Component` class heirarchy? I'll download your source and have a look.

Comment: @toiletseat I had to read your comment as soon as you posted it because I spent a lot of time and yes, this was really my mistake. And then I opened SO and saw that you wrote same thing 10 hours ago -_- So that means that you are right :) Thanks! Maybe you'll post this again and I will accept an answer? :)

Comment: the problem was in my custom `description` method which was returning bad NSString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my buggy `description` method:

```
- (NSString*)description {
  NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@, Name: %@, Icon: %@, parent: %@, children: %@", self.title, self.name, self.icon, self.parent];
  return desc;
}
```

Once this method was fixed, debugger started to print correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Both `componentWithRoot:` and `loadAllData` should be returning an `autorelease`d object.

What *toiletseat* said are all good suggestions/questions.   This sounds specifically like a problem internal to your `Component` class.  Would have to see its innards to say more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for attention, yes I undestand that it is surely my implementation errors, but can't detect them at the moment. Posted my classes here https://gist.github.com/904194